# Why does an UPDATE to a column affect the other columns?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

Using Dbeaver, I am trying to add a new column using an existing column to update it. However, after an update to the new column, other column values are changed (to NULL). I am unsure what is the issue?

Before the update:
[image: Before Update]

My statements:

```
ALTER TABLE project1.nhd
ADD "Address" varchar;

UPDATE project1.nhd
SET "Address" = SPLIT_PART("PropertyAddress", ',', 1);
```

After the update:
[image: After Update]

I thought the issue was the method of data transfer, so I tried importing the CSV as a database in Dbeaver and then exporting it to the table and using COPY to import the data into the table. However, the result was the same.

Comment: Aren't you using an unordered `select...limit` to inspect the before/after state? Are you comparing the before/after state of the exact same records, selected by their unique identifier? How big is the table? If you're not making sure you're looking at the same sample, it might be the sampling bias - you could be looking at some records with non-null data the first time around, then looking at some all-null the second time around. Unless there's someone or something else (trigger, recurring cleanup job) that could be wiping your table, I don't see how this could be because of these two queries

Comment: All that you show is an ALTER and an UPDATE.  What is all this stuff about COPY and importing?  Did you do it, or just think about doing it?  If you did it, what exactly did you do?

Comment: @Zegarek Yes, I think after I updated the column I was shown a different sample/view of the table than before. I didn't notice it until you mentioned it. Thank you!